# C# : "Cannot explicitly call operator or accessor"

Tags: c#

I know that questions with this error have been asked a lot, but I have tried everything they suggested and nothing worked.

First of all, I'm new to C#, that's why I can't find a solution for myself :(

My problem: I have this code (if I summarize it a lot)

```
public class ClassA {
  private static int numA;

  public static void MainProcess() {
    numA = ClassB.get_numB(); 
    ...
  }
}

public ClassB {
  private static int numB { get; set; }
  ...
}
```

Now, it get the error `'numB.get' cannot explicitly call operator or accessor` . I have seen that we should write `numA = ClassB.numB` instead, but this time I get the errors : `The property or indexer 'ClassB.numB' cannot be used in this context because the get accessor is inaccessible` and `'ClassB.numB' is inaccessible due to its protection level`.

So, the only thing I have tried and that works is to change numB in `public static int numB`, but I don't really like it to not be a private variable... so, is there a solution?

Thank you !

Comment: If you'd like to access it from outside the class then its not really `private`, is it? if you don't want it to be `public`, then you can try `internal`. You can also have a `public getter` and a  `private setter`

Comment: "but I don't really like it to not be a private variable" - you're trying to access it from a different class. So you're trying to use it as if it's *not* private. Either you want it to be private, and you can only access it within the program text of `ClassB`, or you need to make it public (or internal).

Comment: Modify it as private variable and create a public property to only get/return the value of this private variable.

Comment: @Sujith: It's an automatically-implemented property, so it's *already* backed by a private field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either have it as a private or public variable. If you want to access it, make it public!

Actually, if you just want to make the getter public but the setter private, you can do this:

```
public static int numB { get; private set; }
```

Or you can make it readonly:

```
public static readonly int numB;
```

Then you can set the value of it in the constructor and its value can never change.